# Induction Problem: $\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{j+1}=-\frac{n}{n+1}$

Tags: induction

Prove that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{j+1}=-\frac{n}{n+1}
$$

I know that

```
1.I need prove it by induction
2.this can be helpful :
```

$ n\binom{n-1}{j-1}=j\binom{n}{j}
$

whatever, i tried to do it by induction and i don´t know how i can to go from 
$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1)^j\binom{n-1}{j}\frac{1}{j+1}
$ to
$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{j+1}
$

I mind, I know that

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}\frac{1}{j+1} = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(-1)^j\binom{n-1}{j}\frac{n}{n-j}\frac{1}{j+1} + (-1)^n\frac{1}{n+1}
$ But I can´t continue...

thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides by $n + 1$.
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{n+1}{j+1}=-n$$
And now:

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{n+1}{j+1}=\sum_{j=0}^{n}(-1)^j\binom{n+1}{j+1}-(n+1)=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{j+1}\binom{n+1}{j}+1\right)-(n+1)=0+1-n-1=-n$

This term $\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}(-1)^{j+1}\binom{n+1}{j}$ is an [alternating sum and difference of binomial coefficients](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_Sum_and_Difference_of_Binomial_Coefficients_for_Given_n) and is equal to zero.

However, I didn't use mathematical induction in this proof.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You may want to apply
$${n+1\choose j+1}=\frac{n+1}{j+1}{n\choose j}$$